# Trouble with putting image into array while doing point cloud

Tags: arrays, opengl, for-loop, point-clouds

Hi I'm having trouble putting image data into 3D arrays while doing point cloud with opengl.

These are my two 3D arrays:

```
float*** imgdata;
    imgdata = new float**[576];
    for(int a=0; a<576; a++)
    {
        *(imgdata + a) = new float*[352];
        for(int b=0; b<352; b++)
            *(*(imgdata + a) + b) = new float[1];
    }

float*** texture;
texture = new float**[576];
for(int a=0; a<576; a++)
{
    *(texture + a) = new float*[352];
    for(int b=0; b<352; b++)
        *(*(texture + a) + b) = new float[3];
}
```

and this is where I load in a depth map and a color image

```
GBmp bm0;
GBmp bm1;
bm0.load("depth.bmp");
bm1.load("color.bmp");
```

now I try to put the data of the two images into the 3D arrays using for loops
, this is the part where the problem seems to be.

```
for (int i=0; i<bm0.w; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<bm0.h; j++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<bm0.w; x++)
        { 
            for (int y=0; y<bm0.h; y++)
            {
                texture[i][j][0] = bm1.rgb[x*3+y*bm0.w*3];
                texture[i][j][1] = bm1.rgb[x*3+y*bm0.w*3+1];
                texture[i][j][2] = bm1.rgb[x*3+y*bm0.w*3+2];
            }
        }
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<bm0.w; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<bm0.h; j++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<bm0.w; x++)
        { 
            for (int y=0; y<bm0.h; y++)
            {
                imgdata[i][j][0] = bm0.rgb[x+y*bm0.w];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I start debugging, I only get a blank window without any errors or unhandled exception so I have no idea what went wrong. Any help or advise is greatly appreciated.

Here's the other half of the code.
I'm using those two arrays, imgdata & texture, to draw points on the 3D space.

```
glPointSize (1);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (int i=0; i<bm0.w; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<bm0.h; j++)
            {
                glColor3f(texture[i][j][0]/255, texture[i][j][1]/255, texture[i][j][2]/255);
                x=imgdata[i][j][0];
                y=imgdata[i][j][1];   
                z=imgdata[i][j][2];   
                glVertex3f(x,y,z);    
            }
        }
    glEnd(); 
glutSwapBuffers();

free(imgdata);
free(texture);
```

Comment: How are you using these `imgdata` and `texture` arrays? Since you mention OpenGL, are you using them as arguments to OpenGL functions? If yes, can you show the calls where you use them? I have a good idea of what's probably wrong, but I need to see the usage of the arrays.

Comment: Yes I am. Sorry for the lack of info, I've updated the question.

Comment: Not the problem I thought it might be. I thought you might be using it as texture data since it was called `texture`, but that's not the case. Thanks for adding the additional information.

Comment: Yeah I use "texture" to determine the color of the points of the point cloud. So those for loops, they seem alright to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looping logic looks incorrect. Take a close look at what's happening here:

```
for (int i=0; i<bm0.w; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<bm0.h; j++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<bm0.w; x++)
        { 
            for (int y=0; y<bm0.h; y++)
            {
                texture[i][j][0] = bm1.rgb[x*3+y*bm0.w*3];
                texture[i][j][1] = bm1.rgb[x*3+y*bm0.w*3+1];
                texture[i][j][2] = bm1.rgb[x*3+y*bm0.w*3+2];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like you want to pretty much just copy the data into the arrays you allocated with your own memory layout. The outer two loops iterate over each pixel in your target array (`texture`). Once you're inside these two loops, I believe you just want to copy the corresponding pixel from the source array. Instead, you have another two loops that iterate over each pixel in the source array.

So you overwrite `texture[i][j]` with each iteration of the inner two loops. The result of this is that all the pixels in the target array will have the same value, which is the last pixel in the source array.

Instead, you need something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<bm0.w; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<bm0.h; j++)
    {
        texture[i][j][0] = bm1.rgb[i*3+j*bm0.w*3];
        texture[i][j][1] = bm1.rgb[i*3+j*bm0.w*3+1];
        texture[i][j][2] = bm1.rgb[i*3+j*bm0.w*3+2];
    }
}
```

This simply loops over all pixels, and copies them from source to destination.

Another problem is that you allocate and populate `imgdata` with `[1]` for the last dimension, but then access it with indices `[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]` in the draw code.

Comment: Thank you good sir! I can't get my head around those for loops for days, you explained it nice and clear.\

Comment: I'll have a look into the `imgdata` problem.

Comment: what if I changed imgdata to

`float** imgdata;
 imgdata = new float*[576];
 for(int a=0; a<576; a++)
 {
   *(imgdata + a) = new float[352];
 }`
and then the part for determining point locations to

`x=imgdata[i][j];
 y=imgdata[i][j];   
 z=imgdata[i][j];   
 glVertex3f(x,y,z);` 
I still get nothing though..

Comment: oh my mistake, I didn't set the perspectives right.